# Go to marketing cloud link in marketing cloud connect app not directly logging into SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, connected-apps, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

Mine is a multi-org connected SFMC and when i am trying to open SFMC by clicking on the got to marketing cloud link available on marketing cloud connect app on sales cloud, it is taking me to login page of SFMC instead of directly logging in.

user on SFMC is integrated with sales cloud user and connection is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud are 2 different instances, so even if you have integrated both the clouds, you need to login separately unless you have enabled Single sign on for both the clouds on your network.